# Android studio doesn't show source of error

Tags: android, android-studio

How do I know which line this is happening at? In Eclpise, if a file had an error, it would be marked, but I can't seem to find that setting in android studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to cast an ImageView to a TextView. This happens when you try to retrieve your widgets declared in xml files by using findViewById(R.id.my_id) and casting them to the wrong view.

Check all your findViewById method calls and make sure you're not casting them to something else then they are declared in xml.

Comment: Yea, I know the reason why but I have a lot of activities and when I made the xml change it affected a few of them. It's a easy fix but I forgot which activities are affected. I don't want to scour through 40 java files to see which one was affected. I just want to know where its happening (sourcefile and line number)

Comment: You should see the error in the bottom section Android section, under logcat tab. Be sure your log filter is set to Error so you can clearly see you errors (it can be set to debug or info, thus the reason why you don't see logs).

Comment: This is showing up during the gradle build, so it doesn't show up in logcat

Answer (score 0):

In your project structure tab on the left, the class should be underlined in red where the problem is

[image]

Comment: If you double click that line, it should take you to it. Also, what version of AS are you using?

Comment: Tried that too, cause usually that works. I am on 1.2.2